# Resize the table to fit the data grid view C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want my table size to fit the data grid view. The data grid view size is always the same but the table can change in amount of rows and columns.

Here is how I populate the table:

```
public DataTable createGridForForm(int rows, int columns)
{              
    // Create the output table.
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    for (int i = 1; i <= columns; i++)
    {
        table.Columns.Add("column " + i.ToString());
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < rows; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
        // populate data row with values here
        ListBox test = new ListBox();
        myTabPage.Controls.Add(test);
        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    return table;
}
```

And here is how I create the datagridview:

```
private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
{
    DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);

    //DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
    //ID_Column.Width = 200;

    int positionForTable = getLocationForTable();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.BackgroundColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Size = new Size(995, 200);
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Location = new Point(5, positionForTable);
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);                   
}
```

I am getting an error when trying this code:

```
//DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
//ID_Column.Width = 200;
```

the error says that the:

> Index was out of range. It may not be negative and must be smaller than the size

Comment: the data is important, but i need the tables to match the data grid view size

Answer (score 1):

this is it

for the width-

```
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode=System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
```

and for the height --

```
totalRowHeight = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Rows)
                totalRowHeight += row.Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add your datagrid to your tab control before get `Columns[0]` you don't get that error.
Your code should be like that:

```
DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);
DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
ID_Column.Width = 200;
```

**EDIT:**

I add detailed lines to fill your `DataGridView` to it's container.

```
private void createGridInForm(int rows, int columns)
{
    DataGridView RunTimeCreatedDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
    myTabPage.Controls.Add(RunTimeCreatedDataGridView);
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.DataSource = createGridForForm(rows, columns);
    // fill the gridview to its container
    DataGridViewColumn ID_Column = RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Columns[0];
    ID_Column.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
    RunTimeCreatedDataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

Comment: yea it worked thx:) but how can i make my table the same size as the grid

Comment: when you say 'table' what do you mean? if want mean `DataTable` it's not a visible object.

Comment: yes the data table, can i have the data grid view to be at a fixed size and then have the   data table to be the same size

Comment: I added to EDIT section in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

following line can be used to fill extra space with a specific column in a data grid view

```
RunTimeCreatedDataGridView .Columns["column_name"].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

if you set this property of all column to **DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill** then all column takes same width